# @AfterEach annotation ignored in Spring test

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, testing

I'm writing some integration tests utilizing Spring. I cannot get @AfterEach to be respected. I assume it's a version issue or library conflict? I've done this before but unsure why it's not being respected now.

```
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterEach;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;


@SpringBootTest(classes = ConsumerService.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {KafkaIntegrationConfig.class})
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class AuthenticationTransformationTest {

   @AfterEach
   public void afterEach() {
     // this is ignored
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know how I hit your questions for the third time today (not on purpose!)... I would start by figuring out my classpath if I were you. `@RunWith` comes from `junit4` and `@AfterEach` from `junit5`, thus the obvious thing that does (not) happen.

You *really* want to stick with `junit-5` most probably. And if you are questioning where do you get *both* `junit4` and `junit5`, most probably from `spring-boot-starter-test` and an explicit dependency that you have defined. You can always issue `gradle dependencies` look at the output and figure out what dependency is brought by what `jar`.

Here is an example how exclusion would happen :

```
testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
    exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    exclude group: 'org.mockito', module: 'mockito-core'
    exclude group: 'org.mockito', module: 'mockito-junit-jupiter'
}
```

Comment: This was it. I had some weird conflicts and got it all resolved. Things are perfect now. Thanks Eugene!